# how to assign a word from a text file to a variable in python

Tags: python

I have a text file and I need to assign a random word from this text file (each word is on a separate line) to a variable in Python. Then I need to remove this word from the text file.

This is what I have so far.

```
with open("words.txt") as f:    #Open the text file
    wordlist = [x.rstrip() for x in f]
variable = random.sample(wordlist,1)     #Assigning the random word
print(variable)
```

Comment: Does what you have work? If not, what does not work?

Comment: i managed to assign a random word from the text file to a variable, however i am now struggling on how to remove that random word from the text file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`random.choice`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.choice) to pick a single word:

```
variable = random.choice(wordlist)
```

You can then remove it from the word list by another comprehension:

```
new_wordlist = [word for word in wordlist if word != variable]
```

(You can also use [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter) for this part)

You can then save that word list to a file by using:

```
with open("words.txt", 'w') as f:    # Open file for writing
    f.write('\n'.join(new_wordlist))
```

If you want to remove just a single instance of the word you should choose an index to use. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29673949/948550) answer.

Comment: I suspect he also needs to write the `new_wordlist` back out to `words.txt`, although I'm reaching the limits of my mind-reading ability here. :)

Comment: I've added the information he may need, but the intial answer does answer the question in the title.

Comment: Why not `word_list.remove(variable)`?

Comment: @Vincent what if there are two similar words in the file... `filter` is more expressive, but this comprehension is well coined.

Comment: @ReutSharabani: The title isn't what matters; it's the actual question that you have to answer. (But you do answer that, and quite nicely, which is why I upvoted.)

Comment: As a side note, `f.write('\n'.join(…))` has a potential problem: it doesn't include a trailing `'\n'`, which is important to many common text-based formats. But if the only program that will be reading the file is the Python script he showed above, of course, that's not a problem; it's just going to `strip` the last line anyway.

Comment: You do realize that the comprehension will remove duplicate words from the list? Use my method to retain duplicate words.

Comment: @MalikBrahimi your method suffles the word list. To do this without shufflingI've added a note in the end of my answer.

Comment: The new version at the end is wrong. `randint` is a closed interval, not half-open. So this will appear to work for many runs, and then one day raise an `IndexError`. (As the docs for `randint` and `randrange` say about `randint`, "in Python this is usually not what you want")

Comment: @abarnert yeah, I've read your answer and googled that already. Thanks.

Comment: May I ask which answer is correct then? I should of mentioned earlier this is to avoid duplicates.

Comment: If you have two similar kines and want to remove only one, usrle the other solution. If you have two similar lines and both should be removed use this one.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to handle duplicates, and it's not acceptable to reshuffle the list every time, there's a simple solution: Instead of just randomly picking a word, randomly pick an index. Like this:

```
index = random.randrange(len(wordlist))
word = wordlist.pop(index)
with open("words.txt", 'w') as f:
    f.write('\n'.join(new_wordlist))
```

Or, alternatively, use `enumerate` to pick both at once:

```
word, index = random.choice(enumerate(wordlist))
del wordlist[index]
with open("words.txt", 'w') as f:
    f.write('\n'.join(new_wordlist))
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than `random.choice` as Reut suggested, I would do this because it keeps duplicates:

```
random.shuffle(wordlist) # shuffle the word list 
theword = wordlist.pop() # pop the first element
```

Comment: How do you know it's acceptable to reshuffle the list every time?

Comment: @abarnert What do you mean by acceptable? A list can always be shuffled.

Comment: Of course a list can always be shuffled, but then it's a different list. For example, if the original list was in some particular meaningful order, and you want to be able to open it in a text editor and skim through it, well, now you can't, and that might not be acceptable.

Comment: @MalikBrahimi I've added a way to prevent shuffle and keep duplicates in my answer that picks an index rather than a word.